# Making array from type text

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to make array from typed text.
This is what I have but the data keeps changing.

```
//get text from typed box
   var arr = type.split('.') // create and place each sentence on a new line
   for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++  ){ 
       $("#area").html(arr[i]);  //
     }
```

How can i display all the sentence entered into a new line without replacing the previous.

Answer (score 0):

Use [.append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/) instead of [.html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
var arr = type.split('.')
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    $("#area").append(arr[i]);
}
```